# Problem with a function that insert the content of a csv into an array of struct

Tags: c, arrays, function, csv, struct

Ok i've a struct that is like this

```
typedef struct{
    int id;
    char nome;
    char cognome;
    int eta;
    char ruolo;
    squadra team;
    char college;
    int td;
} giocatore;
```

and i've a function that insert the content of a .csv file into an array.
The problem is that my fscanf don't return nothing and my array is always empty.

My .csv is structured in this way

```
1   Kyler   Murray  22  QB  Arizona Cardinals   Oklahoma
2   Nick    Bosa    22  DE  San Francisco   Ohio State
3   Quinnen Williams    22  DE  New York Jets   Alabama
4   Clelin  Ferrell 22  DE  Oakland Raiders Clemson
```

-Declaration of the array

```
FILE* file_giocatori;
giocatore* lista_giocatori[numero_giocatori];
```

-Declaration of the function:

```
void giocatori_in_array(FILE* f, giocatore array_giocatori[]);
```

-How i call the function:

```
giocatori_in_array(file_giocatori,*lista_giocatori);
```

-Function:

```
void giocatori_in_array(FILE* f, giocatore array[numero_squadre]){
    size_t count = 0;
    while(fscanf(f, "%d,%s,%s,%d,%s,%s,%s\n", &array[count].id, &array[count].nome, &array[count].cognome, &array[count].eta, &array[count].ruolo, &array[count].team.nome, &array[count].college) == 7)
    {
        printf ("%s %s", &array[count].nome, &array[count].cognome);
        count++;
    }
}
```

The printf don't show me what i swear, seems like my while is blocked at the first cicle

Comment: Some items have spaces. `%s` does not expect spaces. Maybe read whole line and use [strok](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok) instead.

Comment: The commas in `fscanf` aren't needed. In fact, they're probably what's causing your issue.

Comment: the .csv is in te format 1;Name;Surname;field4;field5;field6;field7 i've posted this version for legibility

Comment: you suppose _nome_ and _cognome_ are array of _char_ but they are only _char_, you write/read out of them, see my answer

Comment: Lisibility is indeed important, but it you fail to give the exact format, we won't be able to guess it, and will propose ways that will not work :-(.

Comment: @SergeBallesta yes the OP missed the comma in the csv file, else not possible to know for instance where a state name finishes and where he college name starts. The problem of _char_ rather than array of _char_ also exist in _team_

Comment: The csv file does not use commas but semicolons which is more common in south european languages like French or Italian.

Comment: @ClaudioRizzi are you using ';' or ',' in the csv ? Your remark says ';' but the _fscanf_ format says ','

Comment: While not optimal, you can replace your last `%s` with `%[^\n]` to read *Field7*, including the whitespace, e.g. `while (fscanf( f, "%d,%s,%s,%d,%s,%s,%[^\n]", ...` NONE of the character conversions will work if you declare, e.g. `char nome;` instead of `char nome[64];`, etc.. And in that case since `nome` will already be converted to a pointer on access, you will drop the `'&'` before the variable, e.g. `array[count].college` for all array types. See [C11 Standard - 6.3.2.1 Other Operands - Lvalues, arrays, and function designators(p3)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.1p3)

Comment: @ClaudioRizzi you have several problems in your code, I edited my answer to explain them and also to add a proposal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The printf don't show me what i swear

there are several errors in your code producing that unexpected behavior.

---

In

> ```
> while(fscanf(f, "%d,%s,%s,%d,%s,%s,%s\n", &array[count].id,
>                &array[count].nome, &array[count].cognome,
>                &array[count].eta, &array[count].ruolo,
>                &array[count].team.nome, &array[count].college) == 7)
> ```

and

> ```
>    printf ("%s %s", &array[count].nome, &array[count].cognome);
> ```

you suppose *nome* and *cognome* and *ruolo* and *college* are array of *char* but they are only *char* :

> ```
> char nome;
> char cognome;
> ...
> char ruolo;
> ...
> char college;
> ```

so you read/write out of these fields, and you very probably have the same problem for *nome* in *team*.

The simple way is to use arrays, for instance ( I use arbitrarily a size of 16 for the strings except *rualo* which seems to use only 2 characters out of the ending null character)  :

```
typedef struct{
    int id;
    char nome[16];
    char cognome[16];
    int eta;
    char ruolo[3];
    squadra team;
    char college[16];
    int td;
} giocatore;
```

and

```
while(fscanf(f, "%d,%15s,%15s,%d,%2s,%s,%15s\n", &array[count].id,
             array[count].nome, array[count].cognome,
             array[count].eta, array[count].ruolo,
             array[count].team.nome, array[count].college) == 7)
```

and

```
printf ("%s %s", array[count].nome, array[count].cognome);
```

or more probably

```
printf ("%s %s\n", array[count].nome, array[count].cognome); /* add \n */
```

and do the same for *nome* in *team* (the definition is hidden).

You can also use pointer to *char* for *nome* and *cognome* and *ruolo* (and the same for *nome*  in *team*) :

```
typedef struct{
    int id;
    char * nome;
    char * cognome;
    int eta;
    char * ruolo;
    squadra team;
    char * college;
    int td;
} giocatore;
```

and

```
char nome[16];
char cognome[16];
char ruolo[3];
char college[16];

while(fscanf(f, "%d,%15s,%15s,%d,%2s,%s,%15s\n", &array[count].id, nome,
             cognome, array[count].eta, array[count].ruolo, 
             array[count].team.nome, college) == 7) {
  array[count].nome = strdup(nome);
  array[count].cognome = strdup(cognome);
  array[count].ruolo = strdup(ruolo);
  array[count].college = strdup(college);
```

Do not forget in that case to *free* the dynamic allocated arrays of *char* when you remove entry/entries or *array* to not create memory leaks.

---

Also having

> ```
> giocatore* lista_giocatori[numero_giocatori];
> ```

the call

> ```
> giocatori_in_array(file_giocatori,*lista_giocatori);
> ```

is invalid because `*lista_giocatori` is `lista_giocatori[0]` which is a *giocatore* but `giocatori_in_array`  waits for an array of *giocatore*.

Can be

```
giocatore lista_giocatori[numero_giocatori];
...
giocatori_in_array(file_giocatori, lista_giocatori);
```

---

`giocatori_in_array` do not receive the size of *array* so you also have the risk to write out of *array* in there are more entries in the files than the value of `giocatori_in_array`.

You also need to know how much entries in the array are set, a way is to return that number rather than to have a *void* function.

---

Out of these invalid memory accesses you cannot use *fscanf* to read several words through a single `%s`, so you need to read the rest of the line after the *ruolo* to extract the state and the college, and in case the *nome* and *cognore* can be on several words too you cannot use at all *fscanf* and you have to read all the line then to extract the fields for instance using *strtok* and *strtol* to get the number values.

Note the comma/semicolon are missing in your example of csv file to separate the fields. Your *fscanf* format supposes you use comma, not semicolon as you indicate in a remark of your question.

---

A proposal can be :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct {
  char * nome;
} squadra;

typedef struct{
    int id;
    char * nome;
    char * cognome;
    int eta;
    char * ruolo;
    squadra team;
    char * college;
    int td; /* unused */
} giocatore;

size_t giocatori_in_array(FILE* f, size_t sz, giocatore array_giocatori[]);

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
  if (argc != 2)
    printf("Usage : %s <csv file>\n", *argv);
  else {
    FILE* file_giocatori = fopen(argv[1], "r");

    if (file_giocatori == NULL)
      fprintf(stderr, "cannot open '%s'\n", argv[1]);
    else {
      const size_t numero_giocatori = 16;
      giocatore lista_giocatori[numero_giocatori];
      size_t n = giocatori_in_array(file_giocatori, numero_giocatori, lista_giocatori);

      fclose(file_giocatori);

      /* debug */
      for (size_t i = 0; i != n; ++i) {
        printf("id:%d nome:'%s' cognome:'%s' eta:%d ruolo:'%s' team:'%s' college:'%s'\n",
               lista_giocatori[i].id,
               lista_giocatori[i].nome,
               lista_giocatori[i].cognome,
               lista_giocatori[i].eta,
               lista_giocatori[i].ruolo,
               lista_giocatori[i].team.nome,
               lista_giocatori[i].college);
      }

      /* free resources */
      for (size_t i = 0; i != n; ++i) {
        free(lista_giocatori[i].nome);
        free(lista_giocatori[i].cognome);
        free(lista_giocatori[i].ruolo);
        free(lista_giocatori[i].team.nome);
        free(lista_giocatori[i].college);
      }
    }
  }

  return 0;
}

size_t giocatori_in_array(FILE* f, size_t sz, giocatore array[])
{
  size_t count = 0;
  char line[256];

  while ((count < sz) && fgets(line, sizeof(line), f)) {
    char * s = strtok(line, ",;");

    if ((s == NULL) || (sscanf(s, "%d", &array[count].id) != 1)) {
      fprintf(stderr, "invalid id line %zu\n", count);
      break;
    }

    if ((s = strtok(NULL, ",;")) == NULL) {
      fprintf(stderr, "invalid nome line %zu\n", count);
      break;
    }
    array[count].nome = strdup(s);

    if ((s = strtok(NULL, ",;")) == NULL) {
      fprintf(stderr, "invalid cognome line %zu\n", count);
      break;
    }
    array[count].cognome = strdup(s);

    if (((s = strtok(NULL, ",;")) == NULL)  || (sscanf(s, "%d", &array[count].eta) != 1)) {
      fprintf(stderr, "invalid eta line %zu\n", count);
      break;
    }

    if ((s = strtok(NULL, ",;")) == NULL) {
      fprintf(stderr, "invalid ruolo line %zu\n", count);
      break;
    }
    array[count].ruolo = strdup(s);

    if ((s = strtok(NULL, ",;")) == NULL) {
      fprintf(stderr, "invalid team nome line %zu\n", count);
      break;
    }
    array[count].team.nome = strdup(s);

    if ((s = strtok(NULL, ",;\n")) == NULL) {
      fprintf(stderr, "invalid college line %zu\n", count);
      break;
    }
    array[count].college = strdup(s);

    count += 1;
  }

  return count;
}
```

Compilation and execution:

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -pedantic -Wall -Wextra c.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ cat f.csv 
1;Kyler;Murray;22;QB;Arizona Cardinals;Oklahoma
2;Nick;Bosa;22;DE;San Francisco;Ohio State
3;Quinnen;Williams;22;DE;New York Jets;Alabama
4;Clelin;Ferrell;22;DE;Oakland Raiders;Clemson
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out f.csv 
id:1 nome:'Kyler' cognome:'Murray' eta:22 ruolo:'QB' team:'Arizona Cardinals' college:'Oklahoma'
id:2 nome:'Nick' cognome:'Bosa' eta:22 ruolo:'DE' team:'San Francisco' college:'Ohio State'
id:3 nome:'Quinnen' cognome:'Williams' eta:22 ruolo:'DE' team:'New York Jets' college:'Alabama'
id:4 nome:'Clelin' cognome:'Ferrell' eta:22 ruolo:'DE' team:'Oakland Raiders' college:'Clemson'
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

Execution under *valgrind* :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ valgrind ./a.out f.csv 
==4207== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==4207== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==4207== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==4207== Command: ./a.out f.csv
==4207== 
id:1 nome:'Kyler' cognome:'Murray' eta:22 ruolo:'QB' team:'Arizona Cardinals' college:'Oklahoma'
id:2 nome:'Nick' cognome:'Bosa' eta:22 ruolo:'DE' team:'San Francisco' college:'Ohio State'
id:3 nome:'Quinnen' cognome:'Williams' eta:22 ruolo:'DE' team:'New York Jets' college:'Alabama'
id:4 nome:'Clelin' cognome:'Ferrell' eta:22 ruolo:'DE' team:'Oakland Raiders' college:'Clemson'
==4207== 
==4207== HEAP SUMMARY:
==4207==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4207==   total heap usage: 23 allocs, 23 frees, 5,637 bytes allocated
==4207== 
==4207== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==4207== 
==4207== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==4207== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 6 from 3)
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

The proposal accepts both comma and semicolon to separate the columns in the csv file, but it supposes there are no space(s) around the names (if a name has spaces around it they are not removed, you have to do that if needed).

If you do not have *strdup* :

```
char * strdup(char * s)
{
    char * r = malloc(strlen(s) + 1);

    strcpy(r, s);
    return r;
}
```

Comment: Good write up, I would just also mention that if using `-std=c99` or `c11`, `strdup` will likely not be available. In that case they can simply write a trivial replacement.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin you are right (I will put a full proposal)